# Как транспонировать матрицу по отдельным позициям? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно все вхождения строки в таблицу использовать для вывода значения из этих строк в отдельный столбец. Предположим, что мы знаем максимальное количество вхождений и сформировали таблицу корректно, не забыв упорядочить по одному из столбцов (это отдельный вопрос и я вроде бы разобрался с динамическим количеством столбцов). Объясню на примере:

#### таблица Т:

элемент | значение

item 1 | 5

item 1 | 6

item 2 | 7

item 3 | 8

item 2 | 9

#### Нужно привести к виду

Элемент | вхождение 1 | вхождение 2

item1 | 5 | 6

item2 | 7 | 9

item3 | 8

Comment: если вы разобрались с динамическим числом столбцов, то в чем вообще проблема у вас?

Comment: С тем, что именно в эти столбцы запрашивать. То есть, я могу заранее посмотреть максимально число вхождений, через цикл сформировать строку запроса с нужным количеством столбцов, а потому выполнить(строка_запроса). Но вот что именно в эту строку на каждой итерации добавить, не совсем понятно.

Comment: дак вы знакомы с оператором `PIVOT` в итоге? Если нет, то он решит вашу задачу. Он если вы скливаите строку запроса, то вьюху то вы никак не сделаете, хранимку только.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

формально, ваша задача это не транспонирование в математическом смысле, а создание сводной таблицы. Для этих целей в TSQL существует оператор `PIVOT` (а также обратный ему `UNPIVOT`).
К сожалению, оператор этот  не работает с динамическим набором столбцов. Поэтому для таких случаев приходится строить запрос в виде строки и затем выполнять его. Что в целом не совсем подходит под ваши задачи создания представления (`view`). Поэтому тут можно рассчитывать на хранимые процедуры.

*Исходные данные*

```
create table #t (item varchar(10), value int);

INSERT INTO #t 
VALUES ('item1', 5), ('item1', 6), ('item2', 7),('item3', 8),('item2', 9);
```

Столбцы, как вы уже писали, собираем динамически в строку. Для всего этого определим несколько переменных (здесь `@maxN` - число результирующих столбцов):

```
DECLARE @maxN int = (select top 1 count(value) from #t group by item order by count(value) desc);
DECLARE @n int  = 1;
DECLARE @nStr VARCHAR(3);
DECLARE @strSel varchar(1024) = '',
        @strFor varchar(512) = '',
        @sql nvarchar(MAX) = '';
```

Динамически сформируем строки в цикле:

```
WHILE (@n <= @maxN) BEGIN
    SET @nStr = cast(@n as nvarchar);
    SET @strSel += ',[' + @nStr + ']' + ' as col' + @nStr;  

    SET @strFor += (case when @n > 1 then ',' else '' end) + '[' + @nStr + '] ';    
    SET @n += 1;
END;
```

Далее склеим все в строку SQL-запроса и вполним.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT pt.item' + @strSel + '
           FROM (
              select item, value, row_number() over (partition by item order by value) as colIdx
              from #t
            ) as data
            PIVOT ( SUM(data.value) FOR colIdx in (' + @strFor + ') ) as pt';
print @sql;

execute sp_executesql @sql;
drop table #t;
```

Сам полученный запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT pt.item,[1] as col1,[2] as col2
FROM (
    select item, value, row_number() over (partition by item order by value) as colIdx
    from #t
) as data
PIVOT ( SUM(data.value) FOR colIdx in ([1] ,[2]) ) as pt
```

А результаты его выполнения:

```
item       col1        col2
---------- ----------- -----------
item1      5           6
item2      7           9
item3      8           NULL
```

Comment: Эх, ваши бы труды, да чуть раньше :) Тоже времени зря не терял за эти сутки, ожидая пока всю работу сделают добрые люди. В итоге, сборщик (уж его работу не буду приводить) формирует строку запроса. Те же основные пункты (количество столбцов, цикл формирования строки). Хотя, у меня в конце пришлось еще один внешний запрос делать, но выполняется за секунду, поэтому уж не стану переделывать, хотя для опыта изучил ваши выкладки. И да, пришлось хранить в процедуре из-за динамического количества столбцов. Спасибо!

Comment: @VitaliyYandulov не за что! вы бы на комментарии к вопросу отвечали оперативней, и ответ был бы раньше :) тут кстати еще вопрос эффективности `pivot`-а надо изучить, относительно числа столбцов, возможно он и не будет эффективным способом. Аналогичную таблицу можн построить и через `case`-оператор в селекте, типа `select item, sum(case when colIdx = 1 then value else 0 end) as col1, .... group by item`

Comment: Вот-вот, через case и делал. Но потом потребовался еще внешний запрос чтобы таблицу:

item1 | NULL | 6 ;

item1 | 5 | NULL ;

item2 | NULL  | 9 ;

item2 | 7 | NULL ;

item3 | 8 | NULL ;

Привести в божий вид

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вас устроит следующий вариант:

```
create table #t (item varchar(10), num int);

insert #t values('item1', 5), ('item1', 6), ('item2', 7), ('item3', 8), ('item2', 9);

select item, (
    select stuff(
        (select ',' + convert(varchar(10), num)
         from #t as t1
         where t1.item = t2.item
         for xml path (''))
        , 1, 1, ''))
from #t as t2
group by item;

drop table #t;
```

Результат будет получен в двух колонках в виде:

```
item1   5,6
item2   7,9
item3   8
```

Comment: объединять значения в строк то вроде не требовалось, а скорее наоборот?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению. У меня эскалации заявок попадают в таблицу и нужно вьюху сделать, где целиком брать первое вхождение (а остальные приписывать сбоку когда и какой отдел взял в работу по каждой заявке, т.е. там несколько столбцов для каждого вхождения). И вот я голову уже сломал как это сделать.